# Why default parameters must always be on the right side of any non-default parameters in all programming languages?

Tags: php, function, compiler-construction, interpreter

"Note that when using default arguments, any defaults should be on the right side of any non-default arguments; otherwise, things will not work as expected."

The above sentence is quoted from 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

I remember that all the programming languages I've passed by has the same exact rule for the defaulted parameters, I was wondering, why is that? Is there some sort of a compiler or interpreter rule or restriction which makes this a must? Or can this rule be fixed if let's say I wanna make my own compiler?

Comment: You can always make your own compiler, but this is an issue of practicality.... PHP reads and assigns arguments from left to right; so if you have a function `a($b,$c=1)` and call it using `a(5)`, PHP assigns 5 to $b and $c will be assigned the default 1 because you haven't passed a second argument; if you had defined your function `a($b=1,$c)` and call it with `a(5)` it still assigns 5 to $b, but has no idea what to do with $c so it simply errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this restriction is that otherwise it would be impossible to determine which arguments you are trying to pass. Let's assume the following function:

```
function foo($first = 'default', $second = 'default', $third) { ... }
```

And now we're calling it with `foo('custom value', 'another value');`. `another value` is obviously the value for `$third`, but what parameter does `custom value` stand for? `$first` or `$second`? You can only guess and guessing is a really bad thing for a programming language to do, as it limits predictability for the programmer.

A way to fix that would be named parameter passes. In PHP this could look like `foo($first='custom value', 'another value');`. Now it's clear which default value you're trying to overwrite. Python supports syntax like that, but PHP does not (yet). There has been some discussion to add this feature, I think, but it hasn't been done so far.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is simpler than you think. I will base it on the example on the same page you have provides.

Example #5 Incorrect usage of default function arguments

```
<?php
function makeyogurt($type = "acidophilus", $flavour)
{
    return "Making a bowl of $type $flavour.\n";
}

echo makeyogurt("raspberry");   // won't work as expected
?>
```

First, why functions have default parameters? Usually this is to save you some time, so you can provide only non-default values. As arguments are  parssed to function left-to-right, going with the example #5 you see that by executing `makeyogurt("raspberry")` you will get an error. The error is because the first argument (`raspberry`) you have provided to `makeyogurt()` function gets assigned to `$type`, thus making `$flavour` unassigned and throwing an error.

The only way to make the function work with same definition would be to use it as so:

```
echo makeyogurt("acidophilus", "raspberry");
```

While this would work as expected, it would really make our default value of $type in the defition of `makeyogurt()` function obsolete. There would be no point specifying it there if we have to also pass it every time we call the function.

This, the simple solution (and a rule of thumb) is to have all the parameters with default values on the right, like this:

```
<?php
function makeyogurt($flavour, $type = "acidophilus") // <-- NOTE THIS
{
    return "Making a bowl of $type $flavour.\n";
}

echo makeyogurt("raspberry");   // will work as expected
?>
```

Now with this kind of definition, when you call `makeyogurt("raspberry")` you will get the expected result:

```
Making a bowl of acidophilus raspberry.
```

And you will also be able to specify any non-default `$type` when necessary:

```
echo makeyogurt("raspberry", "plasma");
```

This will echo:

```
Making a bowl of plasma raspberry.
```

Answer (score 1):

Because basically if you had: function F($a = 0, $b);
What should you do if you want to call the function with an empty $a? How will the interpreter know you are filling $b not $a?

What about this: function F($a = 0, $b = 0, $c);
And you want to pass $b and $c? F(0, 1)? A and C? B and C?